# Is it a bad practice to route to a pad from its corner?

Tags: pcb-design, routing, pad

I am new to PCB design, I wonder if there are any bad effects by routing it through the corner of a pad. (Top right)

Any input is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I don’t see anything unusual. There may be specific cases where you would not do it - maybe mechanical or high frequencies.

Comment: which pad are you talking about?

Comment: The layout seems fine to me.

Comment: Do you mean "routing through the **corner** of a pad" as on the top right? (All pads are routed through their edges.) If so, then please [edit] the post title and the post itself.

Comment: @jsotola The top right pad

Comment: @Transistor I have edited my wording, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @kartman  Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent Thanks for the feedback too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two problems that I've had with traces to pads are:

1. breakage when resoldering from too high of heat
2. size of the trace

A 45 degree angle trace would change the way the breakage would happen, as it would happen from the side, in some cases it actually might make it more stable as there is not two 90deg angles with respect the the pad (90deg angles make it easier to rip materials)

The 45 actually increases the amount of copper between the trace and pad, which is a better thing.

Answer (score 3):

Routing through a corner of a pad is totally fine.